# Are multiple comparison operators possible in javascript?

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

So i was writing in the Browser console

```
4 < 5
```

true

```
4 < 5 < 10
```

true

```
7 < 4 < 10
```

true

The first two statements look ok, why is the last statement also correct? I would have thought (as in mathematics) the expression would be 'AND'ed ? can any one point me to MDN or similar resource which talks about this and the rules ?

Comment: As usual in Javascript, what it looks like might be happening is in fact something entirely different and weird due to type coercion. I expect answers will explain in details that yo ain't comparing what yo think yo be comparing.

Comment: True and false are coerced to 1 and 0 in a numeric context, both of which are less than 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log( false < 10) // true
console.log( true < 10) // true
```

because false (0) is less than to 10 
and true (1) is also less than to 10.

Comment: i am going to accept your answer (the others may be correct too) but this explains it for me .. true < 10 and false < 10

Answer (score 3):

What Javascript does, is evaluate the left side first:

```
4 < 5 => true
```

It then continues on the rest:

```
true < 10 => true
```

because `true` on the left side is ***coerced*** to a *number* (`1`), and `1 < 10 === true`. (`false` in comparisons with numbers is coerced to `0`).

Check these funny-looking "goofs":

```js
console.log(3 < 2 < 1)

console.log(1 < 1 < 1)
```

Comment: bwah haha.. omg.. wtf.. but thanks for answering.. so its a no-no to just throw expressions like that without much thought !

Answer (score 1):

Beside the not working approach to write a continuing check with more than one copmparison operator, and while the next comparison takes place the the result of the previous comparison, you could take an array and a function for the comparison operator and iterate the items for every pair to check. Then return the result.

```js
const compare = (values, fn) => values.slice(1).every((b, i) => fn(values[i], b));

console.log(compare([7, 4, 10], (a, b) => a < b)); // false
console.log(compare([4, 7, 10], (a, b) => a < b)); //  true
console.log(compare([2, 1, 0], (a, b) => a > b));  //  true
```

Answer (score 0):

`4 < 5` evaluates to `true`. Then `true` is compared with `10`. Javascript converts `true` to `1` and as `1` is smaller than `10` the result is `true`.

With this logic if you try `4 < 5 < 3` this will also return true with the same logic, and `4 < 5 < 1` will return false.